# NativeScript RadListView index

Tags: appium, nativescript

I'm using NativeScript 6.1.1 and I have a RadListView in which I would like to have unique references for each row. One way I was thinking of is if I could get an index field then I could have the 'automationText' fields with the following

```
name0
name1
name2
```

Here is my current template;

```
<RadListView automationText="listing"
             [items]="dataItems"
             [filteringFunction]="filterItems"
             pullToRefresh="true"
             (pullToRefreshInitiated)="onPullToRefreshInitiated($event)">

  <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
      <GridLayout class="itemContainer" rows="50,*" columns="*,100">

        <Label automationText="name" row="0" col="0" class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>

      </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </ng-template>

</RadListView>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
        <Label automationText="name#{index}" row="0" col="0" class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>
```

Comment: You may get the list of items by xpath and click on particular index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the index you may add `let-i="index"` to ng-template and consume it as `automationText="name{{i}}"`

sample:

```
<RadListView [items]="_dataItems" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector">
    <ng-template tkTemplateKey tkListItemTemplate let-item="item"
        let-i="index">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label automationText="name{{i}}"  text="name{{i}}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I feel like there are a few practical things missing from the nativescript documentation